# Multiple Asset source question

Tags: assets

I'm creating a new Craft 3 site and migrating a lot of content from a wordpress setup. I'm wondering if it is better to separate assets into more sources - thus reducing the number of files per directory. An example would be a different asset source per section. Or is it fine to lump them all into one large directory? Is there any performance advantage to the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most sites, there probably wouldn't be a difference, but if you're purely looking at performance and your site has a large number of assets, then 20 sources with 5,000 images and folders in each is going to scale better than a single source with 100,000 images and folders in them.